# Entity framework inserts new record to navigation table inappropriately

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm facing an issue when inserting records with Many to Many navigation property,

I have these models

```
//ModelBase
public class ModelBase
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

//Book
public class Book : ModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PublishedBook> PublishedBooks { get; set; }
}

//Author
public class Author : ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And DTOs called `BookDto` and  `AuthorDto` for transfer data between layers

From the controller I fill data to DTOs and call `Create` method (which is in separate layer) to Save data to database,

```
BookDto bookDto = new BookDto()
{
    Id = model.Id,
    Title = model.Title,
    Authors = model.AuthorIds.Select(c => new AuthorDto { Id = c }).ToList()
}

using (ServiceFactory facory = new ServiceFactory())
{
    factory.Book.Create(bookDto);
}
```

In the `Create` method I map DTOs with POCOs using ValueInjector

```
public void Create(BookDto bookDTO)
{
    Book book = new Book();
    book.InjectFrom<DeepCloneInjection>(bookDTO);
    bookRepository.Add(book);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

And it calls `Add` method in Genaric Repository Base

```
public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
    dbset.Add(entity);
}
```

This inserts data to `Books` table and `BookAuthors` tables appropriately BUT inserts new record into the `Authors` table even if I pass `Authors` which has existing `AuthorIds` for `Book.Authors` from the controller.

Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to attach the existing authors to the context. You could do it like so:

```cs
public void Create(BookDto bookDTO)
{
    Book book = new Book();
    book.InjectFrom<DeepCloneInjection>(bookDTO);
    foreach (var author in book.Authors)
        authorRepository.Attach(author);
    bookRepository.Add(book);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

where the generic `Attach` methods is just implemented calling `dbset.Attach(entity);`. I am assuming that all repositories (`authorRepository` and `bookRepository`) share the same context instance. Otherwise the above won't work.

The fact that the `AuthorId` already exists in the database doesn't matter. EF doesn't check if the Id exists by a query first. If you call `Add` on an object graph of detached entities it tries to insert the whole graph by generating INSERT statements for the parent and for all children. By attaching the children you effectively turn off the INSERT statements for those.